# How to make j2html format 'each' tags correctly

Tags: java, html, j2html

I'm having trouble getting j2html to format all of its generated output. Elements generated by most of the tags work as expected, but the 'each' tag doesn't format.

Consider the following Java method:

```
private void temp() {
    List<String> middle = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");

    String html =
      html(
        body(
          p("Before"),
          ul(
            each(middle, item ->
              li(
                span(item)
              )
            )
          ),
          p("After")
        )
      ).renderFormatted();

    System.out.println(html);
}
```

the generated HTML is:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            Before
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li><span>One</span></li><li><span>Two</span></li><li><span>Three</span></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            After
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

As we can see, the content of the 'each' block is printed as a single unformatted line. How do we fix this?

Comment: Why do you care about this? It will still be rendered the same by the browser.

Comment: to help me debug it. The sample code is a cut down version of what I really want and it's difficult to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also encountered this bug, wherever you use *each*  the text is all rendered in one line, I had already raised a bug here

https://github.com/tipsy/j2html/issues/97

Comment: I'm kinda glad to see that it's a bug - I thought I was doing something wrong!